# Torah source for different views on Torah

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

I was wondering what are some Torah sources for (ironically) having different hashkafas (outlooks) of the torah itself and what HaShem wants from us. (Of course within the realm of Orthodox Judaism because we know reform and conservative is not what the Torah wants)

Comment: Chassidus, mussar, baalei sod, Rambam, Ramban, Maharal, Reb Tzadok... ?

Comment: I’m looking for the mekor for those seforim

Comment: The shevatim probably are the best mekor for one to understand that hashkafa is different depending on who you are. Halacha isn't about you, Hashkafa is. Therefore, if you were from Rueven your hashkafa would've been x if you were from Levi it would've been y etc. You can't know your shevet now, but it's imperative to know yourself truly and to know what's good for you. For what you're at in life. Note, Halacha comes first and Halacha has what to say about everything, thereafter comes Hashkafa. They do go hand and hand at times.

Comment: @user22042 You are asking an interesting question, the real answer is probably the chassidish approach which is that personal divine inspiration continues to affect our understanding of the Torah, independent of textual sources.

Comment: @pcoz what’s the mekor for that?

Comment: @user22042 Conceptually, have a look at this article https://www.hidush.co.il/hidush.asp?id=19457.